# PHP curl HTTPClientError

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm quiet fresh with curl and have some problems with sending curl request.
So i'm trying to send curl request to figo.sandbox to get task_token but response I get is:

```
{ ["status"]=> int(400) ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#614 (6) { ["code"]=> int(30004) ["group"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(15) "HTTPClientError" ["message"]=> string(15) "invalid_request" ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#616 (0) { } ["description"]=> string(35) "Missing mandatory parameter country" } }
```

but in curl body I type country parameter:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "bank_code": "11111111", "country": "de", "credentials": ["test_login", "test_pass"]}');
```

Here is my full curl request:

```
    $access_token = Sessions::get('figo_access');
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.figo.me/rest/accounts");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "bank_code": "11111111", country: "de", "country": "de", "credentials": ["test_login", "test_pass"]}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/xampp/htdocs/immocloud/vendor/figo/figo/figo/ca-bundle.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    var_dump($json);
    curl_close($ch);
```

And i could not find any solution so I wrote to figo support and after few days i get response to try this command in CLI:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
```

"bank_code": "11111111",
"country": "de",
"credentials": ["test_login", "test_pass"]
}' "https://sandbox.figo.me/rest/accounts"

And it worked. So maybe any ides what i'm doing wrong in php curl?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: why you have `country` twice? `country: "de", "country": "de",` ?

Comment: Not sure if it will fix the problem, but your second call to set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER is going to overwrite the first - you need to add both the Content-Type and Authorization headers to the same array

Comment: @Sharky sorry typing error, should be edited by now.

Comment: @iainn So i tried what you said but i now i get error `{ ["code"]=> int(415) ["group"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(24) "HTTPUnsupportedMediaType" ["message"]=> string(22) "Unsupported Media Type" ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#616 (0) { } ["description"]=> NULL } }` i formed headers like this:
`        $headers = array(
        'Content-type: Content-Type: application/json',
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
        );`

Comment: Looks like just a typo - you've got "Content-Type" in there twice: `$headers = array( 'Content-type: application/json', "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" );`

Comment: @iainn thanks a lot, you are my hero for today :)